Font ebgaramond-maths cannot be found with lualatex and fontspec
For processing pdf printable files with my projects I just switched from pdflatex to now lualatex and need to use the following font ebgaramond-maths with the following MWE getting an error for not finding the requested font:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\scshape,\itshape]{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    
This is just an \textsc{example} sentence \emph{compiled} with LuaLaTeX.

\end{document}

And this is the error message:
! Package fontspec Error: 
(fontspec)                The font "ebgaramond-maths" cannot be found; this
(fontspec)                may be but usually is not a fontspec bug. Either
(fontspec)                there is a typo in the font name/file, the font is
(fontspec)                not installed (correctly), or there is a bug in
(fontspec)                the underlying font loading engine
(fontspec)                (XeTeX/luaotfload).


I already run luaotfloat-tool --update ebgaramond-maths but without success.
Does anybody know what could be the problem?

I don't see an ebgaramond-maths in texlive, there is Garamond-Math.otf  Never use T1 fontenc with luatex or xetex. You would not use a mathfont with \setmainfont which is the fontspec command for the main document text font. The package seems targeted at pdftex, what is your intention here?

@DavidCarlisle There is a package ebgaramond-maths, but it is not a font.

You could, theoretically, use ebgaramond-maths if you don't use Unicode maths. However, I would not recommend using ebgaramond-maths, regardless of engine, if you need to typeset maths. It doesn't support a full complement of characters needed for maths.

I really do NOT need math with this font, I only need the font for text. Except that I needed to use $\bullet$ which seems to be done also with \textbullet.

@DavidCarlisle My intention is to use lualatex for using the font QTFuturePoster. Meanwhile my project file work as indended with lualatex and both this font and ebgaramond. I only need text with ebgaramond.

I don't recommend using ebgaramond-maths for typesetting substantial amounts of maths because it does not provide a full complement of characters for mathematics.
However, if you only need that subset of symbols it can provide or you don't care about my advice, it is possible to do this, even with a Unicode engine, provided you use a traditional setup for maths.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}
    
This is just an \textsc{example} sentence \emph{compiled} with LuaLaTeX.

\[
  \Pr (h/e) = \dfrac{\Pr(e)\cdot \Pr(e/h)}{\Pr(e)} 
\]

\end{document}

This will use Unicode fonts for text and traditional postscript fonts for maths. You do not need to load fontspec separately. Nor do you need to set the main font for the document.

The document will compile with either luaTeX or pdfTeX. The difference is the fonts used for text. In the former case, the opentype fonts will be used; in the latter, the postscript type1. In both cases, type1 will be used for the maths.
If you actively want this configuration and have no independent reason to use luaTeX, I would recommend using pdfTeX in this case as you will then be using the same fonts for text and maths. This is not to say using luaTeX will be problematic - they should match anyway - but, if you've no reason to use it, I would avoid the additional complication of loading EBGaramond in both opentype and type1 format.
A better option for LuaTeX is probably to use Garamond-Math, as David mentioned.
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}
\begin{document}
    
This is just an \textsc{example} sentence \emph{compiled} with LuaLaTeX.

\[
  \Pr (h/e) = \dfrac{\Pr(e)\cdot \Pr(e/h)}{\Pr(e)} 
\]

\end{document}


In this case, you can choose from various 'stylistic sets' according to preference. See Garamon-Math's documentation for details.
Do note that Garamon-Math provides bold, which is not something EBGaramond would provide. Personally, I dislike the idea of violating font designer's intentions in this way, but you are obviously free to do as you will.

Thank you. I suppose to have a reason to use lualatex: I need the font QTFuturePoster which seems to me only available with lualatex or xelatex. Is this correct?

@Thomkrates As far as I know, yes, though I've not checked. Can't you just use Garamond-Math in that case? Although it's possible to use ebgaramond-maths, I don't see any reason you'd want to, really. If you want to be true to the original, just don't use bold.

Yes, in my last 10 projects I did not use bold with ebgaramond-maths (and no math, only garamond text symbols) and pdflatex. Important but is scshape and itshape or emph to me. But bold never. - So in the meanwhile I found a way to not needing QTFuturePoster (since it is also not exactly what I need) - so there is now definetly also no reason for me to use lualatex. But thank you anyway for this short support, I learned my first steps with lualatex although I do not need it at the moment. I love ebgaramond-maths fonts with pdflatex.

@Thomkrates In that case, just be aware of what is missing. There's a table of missing symbols in the documentation. Otherwise, enjoy ;).

Thank you so much, cfr, I will. ;-)
